# why don't created tables in kopring?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin

im starting learning kotlin + spring boot, and try create table by jpa but but dont created table in my code, below is my code

build.gradle.kts

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
...
```

I added jpa like above code and I added jpa like above code and settings jpa and datasource at application.yml like below

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    database: mysql

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: madol
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=Asia/Seoul&useSSL=false
```

after settings make model like below

```
package com.mychew.loginapp.model

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Member(
    var email: String,
    var password: String
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null

    @CreationTimestamp
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()

    fun checkPassword(input_password:String): Boolean{
        return (password == input_password)
    }
}
```

I thought the table should be created automatically when I run the app, but it didn't.

What should I do to solve this problem?

i want advice this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following setting to your configuration:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Though it's only for educational or testing properties. In production you should use DB scheme evolution tools like [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)